# Does this PSU have no regulator?

Tags: power-supply

Regarding [this](https://docs.rs-online.com/94eb/0900766b8169ce78.pdf) adapter, there's big output voltage difference between no load and load condition.

Is this a typical linear supply or missing a regulator? Is it intended to be used for what loads range?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like unregulated linear supply, with just AC transformer, bridge rectifier and bulk reservoir cap.

Unloaded voltage is about sqrt(2) times 12V or 17V.

Comment: Can it be used for a load(fan) which requires 12V 100mA? I cannot reder from manual.

Comment: Theres no load voltage curve. Should I try with a resistor abd see what output voltage is befote wiring to the 12V fan?

Answer (score 1):

> *Is it intended to be used for what loads range?*

The [data sheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/94eb/0900766b8169ce78.pdf) is quite clear: -

[image]

> *Is this a typical linear supply or missing a regulator?*

It's typical of a type of supply circa 1990 but, these days, switch mode power supplies are used because they are more energy efficient, have a regulated output and occupy a smaller volume.

If you look on the [RS website](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/ac-dc-adapters/1391783?gb=s) they say it isn't a switch mode power supply: -

[image]

Comment: But my load is 100mA. What will be the voltage?

Comment: Ask RS to provide that detail. They have a pretty good chat-line. Bottom right hand corner of the page I linked @GNZ <-- having said that, there are some pretty horrible discrepancies in the data sheet compared to the website spec so, if I were you, I'd look for a product that had trustworthy information.

Comment: Unregulated SMPS exist though at the lowest end. So consider slight rewording

Comment: Please supply a link to one.

Comment: Nvm, I had DC/DC converters in mind. AC/DC models are regulated with universal range input indeed

Answer (score 0):

With output voltage range&ripple specifications this looks an unregulated DC power supply with some capacitor following the rectifier.
It can supply up to `450 mA` to loads at no less than 10.44 V (`12 V` - (`5`(spec) + 8(mains)%).
Being unregulated, low loads better be able to withstand 20 V (`17.8 V` + 13%).

Connecting the load will be easiest if it has a receptacle compatible with a plug `2.1x5.5x12mm, centre +`.

(It should run a fan spec'd 12 V, 100 mA just fine, if at about 13 V.)

Comment: Theres no load voltage curve. Should I try with a resistor abd see what output voltage is befote wiring to the 12V fan?

Comment: And where did 8(mains) come from? I cannot see it in the manual

Comment: ±8% is what I remember for local **nominal** mains voltage range: Check yours!

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise you commented `Should I try with a resistor [and] see what output voltage is [before] wiring to the 12 V fan?` to both answers. Measuring (quickly - ~1.2 W!) with a 120 Ωish resistor won't hurt. You could try to find out the fan's max. rated voltage - I'd be surprised if it was less than 14 V.

Comment: @greybeard Note that Eurrope, nominal mains is +/-10% 230V